# Passing Data to D3.js Line Chart with Django Backend

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django, d3.js

I am following a tutorial to create dashboard with D3.js plots. I am facing errors while passing data to the Line Chart plot. I am using the code extracted from [here](https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_basic.html).

Instead of using the data from csv I want to use the data which is extracted from the database. I can't figure out where should the data be referred within the code?

Following is the `index.html` file

```
{% load static %}

<html>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<body> 
    <h1> Hello! </h1>
    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
</body>

<script>

    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
        width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    //Read the data
    // d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/3_TwoNumOrdered_comma.csv",

    var data = {{ AAPL|safe }},
    
      // When reading the csv, I must format variables:
      function(d){
        return { date : d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date), value : d.Close }
      },
    
      // Now I can use this dataset:
      function(data) {
    
        // Add X axis --> it is a date format
        var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }))
          .range([ 0, width ]);
        svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    
        // Add Y axis
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.value; })])
          .range([ height, 0 ]);
        svg.append("g")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    
        // Add the line
        svg.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
          .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
          .attr("d", d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
            )
    
    })
     
</script>
</html>
```

Following is the `views.py` file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from cnxn import mysql_access
import pandas as pd

# Create your views here.
def homepage(request):
    sql = ''' select Date, Close from tbl_historical_prices where ticker = 'AAPL' '''
    cnxn = mysql_access()
    conn = cnxn.connect()
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, con=conn)
    context = {'AAPL':df.to_json()}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

I can't figure out how to pass the data from database to javascript. How can I pass the variable `data` within the javascript?

**Edit**

Currently only **Hello** is displayed on the page. There is an syntax error, I've highlighted the error from console and the page display in below image.

[image]

**Variable d Output**

```
var d = {"Date":{"0":1641168000000,"1":1641254400000,"2":1641340800000},"Close":{"0":182.01,"1":179.7,"2":174.92}},
```

Comment: can you also share the error / output that you are getting?

Comment: I've made the edit with output.

Comment: can you ensure that you are able to access the json values(created from your database) in your `index.html` file?

Comment: I've added variable `d` output extracted from console.

Comment: try this:
```
d3.json(d,
  function(d){
  ..
  ..
  }

  function (data){
  ..
  ..

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and see if this solves your issue,

```
var d = {"Date":{"0":1641168000000,"1":1641254400000,"2":1641340800000},"Close":{"0":182.01,"1":179.7,"2":174.92}};

d3.json(d,
  function(d){
  ..
  ..
  },

  function (data){
  ..
  ..

})
```

Comment: Still not working. I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Date')`

Comment: @Lopez - I think you need to check & format the way the data is passed to the `d3.json` function.